# How to play audio stream into angular 2?

Tags: angular

i used [this package](https://github.com/palmerabollo/bingspeech-api-client) for text to speech. its given audio stream. i tried

```
const client = new BingSpeechClient(this.subscriptionKey);
        client.synthesizeStream('I have a dream').then(audioStream => {
        const audio = new Audio()
        audio.src = audioStream
        });
```

its not working because we need to pass   audio.src = audio url. please help me how to play audio stream